# 5 numbers whose sum is 1 and their squares sum is 11, maximum value of their cubes

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

What will be the maximum of the sum of cubes of 5 numbers where the sum of these numbers is 1 and the sum of the squares of these numbers is 11. I am guessing the answer is 25 (3, -1, -1, 0, 0 being the numbers). But how do we find these using Lagrangian multipliers?

Comment: Are the "numbers" required to be integers (as your solution suggests), or are they allowed to be real numbers (as the desire to use Lagrange multipliers suggests)?

Comment: None of the people who voted to close has the slightest idea of an elegant solution. To save their faces they slammed the closing hammer.

Comment: I also against closing  the thread. I see no reason for this.

Comment: The mullahs of MSEtical correctness notwithstanding I publish here my solution in two comments. – The given plane and the $S^4$ intersect transversally in a compact $S^3$. Therefore the maximum will be brought to the fore by Lagrange's method. One obtains the five equations $3x_i^2-2\lambda x_i-\mu =0$. Whatever the values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ te $x_i$ can have at most two different values $u$, $v$. We therefore have to deal separately with the systems (i) $(5u=1 ,\  5u^2=11)$, (ii) $(4u+v=1, \ 4u^2+v^2=11)$, (iii) $(3u+2v=1, \ 3u^2+2v^2=11)$.

Comment: The first has no solutions, for (ii) we obtain $u=(2\pm3\sqrt{6})/10$, $v=(1\mp6\sqrt{6})/5$, and for (iii) we obtain $u=(1\pm6)/5$, $v=(1\mp9)/5$. Comparing the resulting sums of cubes it turns out that the maximum is at (ii), $u=(2-3\sqrt{6})/10$, $\>v=(1+6\sqrt{6})/5$, and takes the value $(163+243\sqrt{6})/25\approx30.329.$

Answer (score 2):

The constraint functions are
$$g_1(x) = \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i - 1$$
$$g_2(x) = \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^2 - 11.$$

The function to maximize is

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^3.$$

The Lagrange conditions $\nabla f = \lambda_1 \nabla g_1 + \lambda_2 \nabla g_2$ read (component-wise)

$$3x_k^2 = 2\lambda_1x_k + \lambda_2, \text{  for } k = 1,2,3,4,5$$
$$g_j(x)=0, \text{  for } j = 1,2$$

Solving these is a bit tedious, but we get

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{3}{20}(4+9\sqrt 6)$$
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{3}{50}(106-9\sqrt 6)$$

and one of the components of $x$ is
$$\frac{1+6\sqrt 6}{5}$$
and others are 
$$\frac{1-3\sqrt {\frac{3}{2}}}{5}$$

This gives the maximum value of $f$

$$\frac{163+243\sqrt 6}{25} \approx 30.329$$

Comment: How exactly did you solve for the Lagrangian multipliers? and is it necessary to solve for these, is there not a method to solve for the values of x without getting the multipliers directly? (cause i guess there is)

Comment: @vignesh As the question is put on hold, I guess it doesn't matter anymore but I just used Wolfram Alpha.